# Calculate $\|f\|$ with $f(x) = \int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt - 2x(0)$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> In $C[-1,1]$, consider the norm $\|x\|  = \max\{x(t)\mid t \in [-1,1]\}$ and $f(x) = \int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt -
>  2x(0)$, $x \in C[-1,1]$. Find $\|f\|$

Hi everybody. I got stuck in this problem. I can prove that $||f|| \le 4$, but I can't find any continuous function $x \in C[-1,1]$ such that $\|f(x)\| = 4\|x\|$. Can anyone help me. Thanks

Comment: @M.Strochyk: For any constant function $x(t),$ $f(x)$ will yield a very particular value. Only one such function will give the result the OP is looking for.

Comment: Please consider adding $x \neq 0$, or you will read infinitely many trivial answers :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a sequence $x_n \in C[-1,1]$ such that

a) $x_n(t) = 1$ for all $t\in [-1, -1/n]\cup [1/n,1]$

b) $x_n(0) = -1$

c) $x_n(t)$ is the line joining $(-1/n,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ on $[-1/n,0]$

d) $x_n(t)$ is the line joining $(0,-1)$ and $(1/n,1)$ on $[0,1/n]$

Then, $\|x_n\| = 1$ for all $n$, and
$$
f(x_n) \sim 2 - \frac{2}{n} + 2 \to 4
$$
Hence, $\|f\| = 4$

Comment: I am not able to think of a function $x$ such that $|f(x)| = 4\|x\|$; so this is the best I can do!

Comment: Except for $x = 0$, there is no function with $\lVert f(x)\rVert = \lVert f\rVert\cdot \lVert x\rVert$. You can't do better.

Comment: +1: Very nice, Prahlad. Thanks to you and @Daniel for pointing out what I was missing about the context.